# Generar un aleatorio mientras en la db no exista uno igual

Tags: php

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código para generar una secuencia de letras y números.

```
function aleatorio($longitud, $tipo=0){
    $codigo = "";
    $caracteres="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $max=strlen($caracteres)-1;
    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++)
    {
        $codigo.=$caracteres[rand(0,$max)];
    }
    return $codigo;
}
```

y llamo la función para que me entregue un aleatorio.

Mi nuevo problema es que necesito crear un aleatorio y comprobar que no exista en la base de datos y no se como hacerlo, la idea es que sea un aleatorio único en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Qué estas utilizando PDO o mysqli? seria bueno que editaras tu pregunta agregando esa información

Comment: ¿Quieres verificar si el código existe en la base de datos?

Comment: SI quiero comprobar si el código generado ya existe la idea es que genere uno nuevo y que no se repita, y para esto puede ser MYSQLI, gracias.

Comment: ¿Porque utilizas un for?

Comment: No se si me hice entender, necesito generar un aleatorio único por eso debo comparar el que genera la función con lo que hay en la base de datos para asegurar que sea único.

Comment: ¿Al guardar los registros en la base de datos almacenas un código? Puedes dar mas información como base de datos, controlador o modelo para así poderte ayudarte y entender.

Comment: en la base de datos se guarda el aleatorio que se genera por ejemplo: asdf7adf780 la idea es que cuando se vuelva a generar un aleatorio no se repita asdf7adf780 ya que ese esta en la base de datos, como puedes ver tengo la función con la que genero, pero no se como usar un while o algo similar para que me repita la función si el numero aleatorio ya existe en la base de datos.

Comment: Si ya entiendo lo que quieres hacer. ¿Estas utilizando MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto te funciona solo tienes que adaptarlo a tu tabla de la base de datos

```
function token()
{
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
    return $token;
}
```

Esta función te crea números aleatorio la puedes llamar cuando estés guardando en la base de datos y para hacer la comparación con los registros ya existentes

```
$token = token();
```

Aquí haces el llamado a la función al cual lo vas a poder manipular en tu PHP para hacer las respectivas comparaciones

```
$sql = "SELECT tu_campo_aleatorio FROM tu_table WHERE tu_campo_aleatorio = '".$token."'";
```

Tu consulta en la base de datos para verificar si ya existe ese código

Y finalmente....

```
if($sql == TRUE)
{
    //Tu código
    echo "Ya existe este código en la base de datos";

}else{

    //Tu código
    echo "Puedes utilizar este código";
}
```

Devuelves el resultado obtenido.

Comment: y en el caso de que ya exista como hago para volver a ejecutar esa porción de código que genere de nuevo el token hasta que genere uno que no exista?

Comment: La verdad es que es casi imposible que se repita el código.